# Edimax EW-7811Un cannot connect to wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-zero

I have a [Edimax EW-7811UN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003MTTJOY) wifi dongle, and I'm trying to get it to connect to my wifi when plugged into a raspberry pi zero.

First off, the pi zero has a single usb port so I can only have either my keyboard or the dongle connected, not both at the same time. I tried plugging the dongle into my keyboard's usb port, but then when I check dmesg I see the error:

`No support over 100mA`

So I'm stuck connecting one device at a time I guess.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` contains:

```
auto lo
iface lo

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

My `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` contains:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="MYSSID"
    psk="MYPSK"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Where `MYSSID` and `MYPSK` are set to my router's ssid and password.

If I then kick off `watch ifconfig`, then disconnect my keyboard and connect the dongle, I see a wlan0 entry appear. However, it never gets an ip address, and the RX `dropped` count slowly increases, but `packets`, `errors`, `overruns`, and `frame` stay at zero. Also, nothing changes for `TX`.

Does anyone have any tips for getting this to connect? I've already invested about 8 hours of troubleshooting and trial/error and I'm not sure what to try next.

> Other changes I made:
>
> To the file `/etc/rc.local`
>
> ```
> modprobe 8192cu
> ifdown wlan0
> ifup wlan0
> ```
>
> Without the `modprobe 8192cu` line, the 8192cu driver doesn't load.
>
> I also disabled power saving as described [in this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/27751/31426).

Comment: Can you try using a higher current rating Adapter ? It is strongly advised to use __2 A__ current rating or more!

Comment: @Shan-Desai I ordered another adapter, so I'll report back once it arrives and I get a chance to try it out.

Comment: Am I missing something here but what about using a Powered USB hub - that _is_ the recommendation for other RPi models connecting to power hungry USB devices and some WiFi dongles are known to have a current consumption above the 100mA level...?

Comment: @Shan-Desai no luck. I'm running it through a **5V 2.4A** adapter now, but the results are the same.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting. Let me do some research and get back to you ASAP

Comment: FYI I just tried following http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip/37921#37921 without luck.

Comment: I just realized that the wifi dongle is 2.4GHz only, and the endpoint I was trying to reach was on 5GHz. \*facepalm\* I switched over to my 2.4GHz endpoint and it's now working, although I'm seeing some bandwidth issues which I'm off to troubleshoot next.

Comment: What driver do you use for wpa_supplicant, "wext" by any chance? Try running wpa_supplicant with the "nl80211" driver using this option: `-D nl80211`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Make the section for your wlan0 in /etc/network/interfaces look like this:

```
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

In your wpa_supplicant.conf file, make it like this:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
               ssid="YOUR_SSID"
               psk="YOUR_PSK"
}
```

Good luck